# Transfer files via SFTP using Jcraft

Tags: java, sftp

- List item

I can write a java program to transfer files via SFTP. However, that would consist of a script with executable commands.
Can this be achieved with Jcraft?
Let's say, the sample script file is something like this:

```
cd pub
ascii
get filename.txt
put otherFile.txt
bye
```